# rmagick installation problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamhost, rmagick

I am trying to deploy my rails 3 app on DreamHost.
When I do "bundle install", rmagick causes an error.

```
configure: error: Can't install RMagick. Can't find Magick-config or GraphicsMagick-config program.
RMagick configuration failed with status 1.
```

I checked ImageMagick version.

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.3.7 11/16/10 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2008 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

And I checked rmagick version

```
$ ls -d /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick*
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-1.15.14
```

As I don't care the version of rmagick, I changed the rmagick version to 1.15.14 in Gemfile.
But still it gives the same error.

How do I fix this problem? Is it possible that I omit rmagick in Gemfile and add [require 'RMagick'] somewhere? If so, which file do I add it to?

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problems, installing libmagickwand did the trick for me...

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Having ImageMagick is only half of the solution. You also need the development headers. Often this is called `ImageMagick-devel` or something along those lines and depends on your distribution.

Once you have your development version installed you will get the `Magick-config` program.

Comment: Actually rmagick is already installed. It's just a old version. I can require 'RMagick' from irb. That means I don't have to reinstall it. Right?

Comment: If it's already installed, set your `Gemfile` to use that specific version and it won't try and install a new one. Check with `gem list`.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

1. Install my own ImageMagick to my home folder: 
   http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Image_Magick#Compiling_ImageMagick_on_your_DreamHost_account
2. Export relevant path: 
   http://wiki.dreamhost.com/RMagick

Then $ bundle install